# Python - Sum by Unique Attributes in a List of Attributes

Tags: python, list, object, list-comprehension

If I have a list of objects, `listOfObj`, and each object has at least 2 attributes, an `obj.value`, which is a float, and `obj.name`, which is a string, what's the best way to get a sum of all `obj.value` by each unique `obj.name` in the list?

It's pretty much what `groupby` and `sum` does in `pandas`.

I can think of a crude way to do it, but I'd like to know (and I'm pretty sure there is) if there's a more elegant way to do this.

This is the solution I have currently. First, get all unique `name` in `listOfObj`:

```
unique_atts = {obj.name for obj in listofObj}
```

Then, perform individual `sum` operations for each attribute, like

```
sum_n = sum([obj.value for obj in listOfObj if obj.name == unique_atts[n]])
```

Clearly, this is not the best way to do this. What's the optimal way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` after sorting it with `operator.attrgetter('name')` as key.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter
print({k: sum(o.value for o in g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(listOfObj, key=attrgetter('name')), attrgetter('name'))})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `itertools.groupby` to group the objects by name and then get the sum of grouped objects

```
from itertools import groupby
f = lambda x: x.name
d = {name:sum(obj.value for obj in grouped_objs) for name,grouped_objs in groupby(sorted(listOfObj, key=f), f)}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the answer by Mattia Procopio, you could use defaultdict to create a dictionary with integer as the default value, then iterate through the objects to sum the value according to the object.name :

```
from collections import defaultdict
sums = defaultdict(int)
for o in objectlist :
    sums[o.name] += o.value
```

Comment: brilliant, I haven't thought of default dicts for this case

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
sum = {}
for obj in listofObj:
    if obj.name in sum:
        sum[obj.name] += obj.value
    else:
        sum[obj.name] = obj.value
```

If key exists it adds the actual value, if not it inits the sum dict with the new name and set the starting value